# Отключить проверку изменений у 1 из 2 VCS

Tags: teamcity

Имеется 2 vcs:

[image: картинка 1]

Возможно ли в TeamCity отключить автоматическую проверку на изменения для 1 из 2 VCS.

**UPD**
Тригер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: какую проверку ? проверку чего?

Comment: как понять проверка на изменения?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, например, после git push

Comment: что значит да? ))  
как понять "проверку на изменения"?  то есть ты не хочешь чтобы твоя конфигурация стартовала по тригеру на коммит, если в данном репозитории появился коммит ?  т.е. она должна тсартовать только если коммит в определнной репозитории?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, исправил:) Тригер я добавил, вот только выбрать для какой VSC в нем нет возможности, соответственно он следит за обеими. А мне необходимо только для 1. Совершенно не умею изъясняться(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new trigger -> VCS Trigger

тут настраивается триггер на событие в VCS. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нам ужно настроить `Trigger rules:`, который и будет "рулить всем".

Там же можем выбрать конкретный репозторий, для которого будет срабатывать триггер. По умолчанию стоит `<any VCS root>`

также можно использовать [другие фильтры](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-buildTriggerRules). Либо фильтры будут подтягитьваться из самой конфигурации. Это полезно, если разные конфигурации на одной уровне должны сработать по-разному

```
+|-[:[user=VCS_username;][root=VCS_root_id;][comment=VCS_comment_regexp]]:Ant_like_wildcard
```

например, `-:user=some_Dev_user` // исключить этого юзера

```
+:comment=prod // стратовать только при комментарии `prod`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо!!!